# Renaming Printer using C# and WMI

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

I have created a C# application to rename printers on a Citrix server (Server 2008 R2).

The reason for this is because every time a user logs on the printer gets forwarded to the server and gets a unique name(For example Microsoft XPS Document Writer (from WI_UFivcBY4-wgoYOdlQ) in session 3) and from within some applications thats an issue since the printer is pointed to the name and by that you need to change the printer setting everytime you logon a session.

The program itself works like a charm and the printer gets the names I desire.
However the issue is after that the printers have been renamed Windows does not seem to be able to identify them anymore. For example if I try to change default printer i get an error saying "Error 0x00000709 Double check the printer name and make sure that the printer is connected to the network."

```
            var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer where name like '%(%'"); 

            ManagementObjectCollection result = query.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject printer in result)
            {
                string printerName = printer["name"].ToString();

                if (printerName.IndexOf('(') > 0)
                {
                    printer.InvokeMethod("RenamePrinter", new object[] { printerName.Substring(0, printerName.IndexOf('(')).Trim() + " " + userName }); //userName is provided as an inputparameter when running the application
                }
            }
```

Am I missing anything? Are there anything else i need to do when renaming?
I cant seem to find any info regarding this case at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i thing [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80680/Managing-Printers-Programatically-using-C-and-WMI) codeproject is what your looking for. But after some own experiences with the printers in `C#` i can only say it does not make fun and it can be really frustrating

Code with small modifications:

```
//Renames the printer
public static void RenamePrinter(string sPrinterName, string newName)
{
    ManagementScope oManagementScope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
    oManagementScope.Connect();

    SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery();
    oSelectQuery.QueryString = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Name = '" + sPrinterName.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "'";

    ManagementObjectSearcher oObjectSearcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher(oManagementScope, oSelectQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection oObjectCollection = oObjectSearcher.Get();

    if (oObjectCollection.Count == 0)
        return;

    foreach (ManagementObject oItem in oObjectCollection)
    {
        int state = (int)oItem.InvokeMethod("RenamePrinter", new object[] { newName });
        switch (state)
        {
            case 0:
                //Success do noting else
                return;
            case 1:
                throw new AccessViolationException("Access Denied");
            case 1801:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Printer Name");
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello!Thanks for your answer. I have used that page for reference already. I did sense that it could be a hassle. However i have found some interresting details regarding this matter with citrix and printers on this link. I could be the rights that are messing it up [link](http://www.norskale.com/articles/article/programmatically-rename-xenapp-autocreated-client-printers) Again thanks for your post. I will continue my search for hte solution and post here as soons as i find it!

Comment: as stated [here](http://www.scriptinternals.com/new/us/support/Internal/WMI_Win32_Printer.htm), code **5**, and not code **1**, is for **Access Denied**

Answer (score 0):

Still works great in 2022, thank you. Just had to change type

> *int*

to

> *UInt32*

to avoid new Exception:

```
UInt32 state = (UInt32)oItem.InvokeMethod("RenamePrinter", new object[] { newName });
                switch (state)
                {...
```

Comment: Put your code in code block with language so that it can provide better highlights. Like for Javascript

```js

Code

```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33698859)